# No Ad Control (within toolbox) in Visual Studios 2012?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sdk, ads, visual-studio-sdk

I am a seasoned Visual Studios 2010 Windows Phone Developer and I have used ads in many of my apps. I recently upgraded to Visual Studios 2012 and can't find the ad controls in the tool box? The proper library references are there and loaded however there is no actual controls in the tool box to add to the canvas.

I tried installing the pub center ad control that is offered here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8729 but it says that a later version is already installed on this machine and that it wont work.

So what am I missing?

Google results only in one article that relates and it is left open ended.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpinappads/thread/c2b8c26d-c227-4d00-9045-7a613dfc6fe9

Answer (score 3):

Almost as soon as I asked this I realized the answer. I am posting it here so there is some sort of documentation for the future. Please don't delete.

- Right click in tool box
- Click Choose Items
- Check Ad controls
- Hit Ok

Hope this helps in the future.